# Does quartz.net support time windows?

Tags: c#, scheduling, quartz.net

I have a Quartz.net service that is supposed to run every day, every 10 minutes, between 6AM and 9AM only.  I cannot find anything in Quartz that specifically supports time windows, but I may be misreading it, or it could be badly documented.

Is there a way in Quartz to create a trigger that only fires between specified times?

Comment: I'm not sure that it's a duplicate.  CalendarTrigger repeats based off of an interval of time, where I'm looking to fire only within a specified window of time.   In other words, I can use the Calendar Trigger to fire every day (or couple of days) at 6AM, but not to fire only between 6AM and 9AM.  If I'm missing something of how to implement CalendarTrigger to do this, please post that as the answer.

Comment: How about [calendar chaining](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5863435/21727)?

Answer (score 0):

While digging around I found the Quartz.Impl.Calendar namespace which, apart from not being well documented, included DailyCalendar which does precisely this.